# Regular expression validation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate(this);" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/abc_forms" class="niceform" id="new_abc_form" method="post" name="form""><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
   <div class="specify_your_own" id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <label>Specify your own</label>
        <input id="abc_form_git_repos_name" maxlength="32" name="abc_form[git_repos_name]" size="32" type="text" />
        <select name="gitcategory[name]" id="git_category_name">
          <option value="">Select Category</option>
          <option value="a">a</option>
          <option value="b">b</option>
          <option value="c">c</option>
          <option value="d">d</option>
          <option value="e">e</option>
        </select>
        <div id="TextBoxDiv">
            </div>
        <input type='button' value='Add More' id='addButton' style="margin-left: 200px; width: 70px;">
        <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButton' style="width: 70px;">
      </div>
      <div class="specify_your_own">
        <div style="margin-left:200px;" id="text"></div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="svn_field">
        <label class="form_bold">SVN Repository:</label>
        <div class="specify_your_own" id='TextBoxesGroupSecond'>
          <label>Specify your own</label>
          <input id="abc_form_svn_repos_name" maxlength="32" name="abc_form[svn_repos_name]" size="32" type="text" />
          <select name="svncategory[name]" id="git_category_name">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
            <option value="c">c</option>
            <option value="d">d</option>
            <option value="e">e</option>
          </select>
          <div id="TextBoxDivSecond">
            </div>
            <input type='button' value='Add More' id='addButtonSecond' style="margin-left: 200px; width: 70px;">
            <input type='button' value='Remove' id='removeButtonSecond' style="width: 70px;">
        </div>
        <div class="specify_your_own">
          <div style="margin-left:200px;" id="text2"></div>
        </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="instance_submit">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

For the Add More Button I have a jquery function which adds more text boxes with the select tag which is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var counter = 1;
     $("#addButton").click(function () {
  if(counter>6){
            alert("Not allowed to add more then 7 repositories");
            return false;
  }   
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
       .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.html("<label>Specify your own</label>"+"<input type='text' name='abc_form[git_repos_name_"+counter+"]' size='32' maxlength='32' value='' id='abc_form_git_repos_name_"+counter+"' >" + '<select id="git_category_name_'+counter+'" name="gitcategory[name_'+counter+']"><option value="">Select Category</option><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option><option value="d">d</option><option value="e">e</option><option value="f">f</option></select>' + '<br/>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      counter++;
     });
      $("#removeButton").click(function () {
  if(counter==1){
          alert("No more to remove");
          return false;
       }   
  counter--;
         $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
     });
  });
</script>
```

This function adds more button and takes input from the users and restricts the user from having more then 6 inputs.

Now finally, I have a javascript which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ck_git = /^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9_,]*$/;
function validate(form){
  var git1 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_1.value;
  var git2 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_2.value;
  var git3 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_3.value;
  var git4 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_4.value;
  var git5 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_5.value;
  var git6 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_6.value;
  var svn1 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_1.value;
  var svn2 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_2.value;
  var svn3 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_3.value;
  var svn4 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_4.value;
  var svn5 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_5.value;
  var svn6 = form.abc_form_svn_repos_name_6.value; 
  var errors = [];
  if (!ck_git.test(git1)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.1 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(git2)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.2 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(git3)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.3 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(git4)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.4 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(git5)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.5 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(git6)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Git add more No.6 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn1)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.1 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn2)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.2 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn3)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.3 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn4)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.4 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn5)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.5 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (!ck_git.test(svn6)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "Svn add more No.6 Not Valid - Only letters (A-Z or a-z) and Numbers are allowed. Special characters and space not allowed";
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
    reportErrors(errors);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
  }
  function reportErrors(errors){
  var msg = "Please Enter Valide Data:\n";
  for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
    var numError = i + 1;
    msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
  }
  alert(msg);
}
</script>
```

This JavaScript function validates the reqular expression and returns a sum of errors if the validation failed.

**Problem:** This works fine only if a user has clicked add more 6 times which generates all the id's it is looking for. If the user clicked add more once and fails validation, the form is still submitted. I am a ROR developer and have no idea how to fix this issue.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you change the start of the form HTML to: `<form onsubmit="return (validate(this) && (counter <= 6));"`...? NOTE: This is a hack to find out what the problem is - not meant to be the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they haven't added all of the elements, then lines like this:

```
var git3 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_3.value;
```

will fail, because `form.abc_form_git_repos_name_3` will be `undefined`. Trying to access the `value` property of `undefined` will throw a JavaScript error, and your validation won't complete (the browser will carry on submitting the form in this case).

What you'll need to do is make sure those elements exist before attempting to access their properties:

```
if(form.abc_form_git_repos_name_3)
    var git3 = form.abc_form_git_repos_name_3.value;
```

Passing `undefined` to the `test` function will return `false`, so you'll also need to check that `git3`, etc are set before calling the regular expression:

```
if(git3 && !ck_git.test(git3)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks. But there is one more issue now, imagine the user added 3 buttons among which two are valid and 1 is invalid (failed validation). After he got the alert that it was invalid he removes the input field which failed the validation and clicks on submit. The user still gets the alert with the error that the field was invalid even though he removed it. Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: @Hivltg Just realised I forgot to mention that you'll also need to check the variable is set before applying the regular expression to it. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could add some specific class to your dynamically added input fields, like "**some_class**", and since you are using jQuery, you could use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), like:

```
var ck_git = /^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9_,]*$/;
function validate(form){
   var errors = [];
  $("input.some_class").each(function(idx, value) {
      if( !ck_git.test(value) ) {
          errors[] = "Git add more No." + idx + ".....";
      }
  });
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    reportErrors(errors);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
)
```